# Tex & friends abroad

Tags: discussion

I've created a small Stack Exchange tag set for Latex &c questions that are not this site, which I've called [`texmf -tex.sx`](http://stackexchange.com/tagsets/334/texmf-tex-sx).

Answer (score 2):

Several of the questions tagged with this tag have also been duplicated on this site. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4107694/219352) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4098356/219352) have both also been asked on the tex.se site.

What is the purpose of this tag?

Comment: I created the tags to get an overview of what Tex-related questions were being asked on other sites.  With both of the questions you link to, the qner was pointed to this site.

Comment: Well, lots of TeX related questions still get asked on StackOverflow, and people are normally pointed to this site fairly quickly. This is an uninteresting subset of TeX related questions being asked elsewhere. I agree it would be interesting to see where else these questions pop up, but the SO ones aren't interesting, in general

Comment: I've upvoted this answer so that the Community user is less busy ...